# A question about the definition of the Tor functor

Tags: algebraic-topology

On pg 278 of Bredon's "Topology and Geometry" says the following"

> Let $0\to A'\to A\to A''\to 0$ be a short exact sequence of abelian groups, and let $M$ be another abelian group. Then the following long exact sequence is induced:
> $0\to Tor(M,A')\to Tor(M,A)\to Tor(M,A'')\to A'\otimes M\to A\otimes M\to A''\otimes M\to 0$

How do we know that the long exact sequence ends at $Tor(M,A')$? That $Tor(M,A')\to Tor(M,A)$ is injective?

Comment: Indeed! In general, the left-derived functors of a right-exact functor like $-\otimes M$ do not become zero ...

Comment: Every abelian group has a free (so in particular flat) resolution of length $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Abelian groups are the same as $\mathbf Z$-modules, and all P.I.D.s have (weak) global dimension $1$, which means every module  over a P.I.D. has a flat resolution of length $\le 1$.